# Include header files optionally in C++

Tags: c++, build, c-preprocessor, bjam

I have a C++ code which needs to include a certain library in some servers and not in other servers. I build my code using bjam.

Code example:

```
if server in server_list:
   include <header-file.h>
   int function();
else:
   int function();
```

And during build using bjam:

```
if server in server_list:
    -llibrary
else:
   ...
```

Comment: How do I define only when running in specific servers?

Comment: @Rajs123 If you're running on different servers that need different libraries you need to build different executables, or use DLLs that you load as needed. (I suspect that you're expecting something similar to `import` in Python. C++ doesn't work that way.)

Comment: I am fine in building different executables, however I would need to mention that in Jam file. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header file inclusion is a compile time activity not run time. So you can't use if conditions for the same

use #ifdefs

```
#define SERVER_IN_LIST

#ifdef SERVER_IN_LIST
    #include<...>
#endif
```

Comment: And how to specify this if else in Jam file?

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ any line that begins with a `#` is a *[pre-processor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) directive*. The pre-processor is a text parser that parses a source code file before it is compiled. It understands particular directives such as `#include`, `#define` and `#ifdef` **but it treats normal C++ code as if it were text**. For this reason, you can't use normal C++ code to alter the interpretation of the pre-processor directives.

Let's look at an example:

```
if (x == 4){
    #include "x4.h"
}
```

The above is wrong because the `if` statement and its braces are part of the C++ code so will be ignored by the pre-processor. The pre-processor will go straight ahead and interpret the `#include` directive, which will cause the contents of `x4.h` to be pasted into that position in the file.

The correct way to write this is to use conditional pre-processor directives such as `#if` or `#ifdef`. For example...

```
#ifdef INCLUDE_X4
#    include "x4.h"
#endif
```

Note that the indentation in this code is optional.

More information about pre-processor directives can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).