# C++ pre-processor #include

Tags: c++, header, include, header-files

I'm trying to make my program into multiple languages, at start the user is asked if he wants language1 or language2.  User input is stored in a variable and then using the if statement I get what language the user chose.

Like this :

```
std::cin >> language;

if(language == ENGLISH)
     {
     // Do something
     }
else if(language == SPANISH)
     {
     // Do something else
     }
```

What I did next is is I stored every function that I want to be translated into two header files, one English and one Spanish, both header files are the exact same, except every output is translated.

Now what i did is something like this

```
std::cin >> language;

if(language == ENGLISH)
     {
     #include "English.h"
     }
else if(language == SPANISH)
     {
     #include "Spanish.h"
     }
```

Now, `#include` is a pre-processor directive so it gets "executed" before  the main function, any way around this ?

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741849/include-header-files-optionally-in-c

Comment: If only i18n was that easy. I'm afraid your desired approach is a non-starter.

Comment: Oh lord. The text in an included file is inserted at compile time. You should implement a data driven approach, meaning load a file (xml, json, ...) depending on the language and use this data.

Comment: Why not read the LANG environment variable?

Comment: You could put all the language specific stuff into a structure or class and pass that around.  Some applications use lookup tables to fetch translated texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, #include is postprocessor directive so it gets "executed" before the main function

It is a **pre**processor directive. It is not "executed" at runtime; The source is pre-processed before compilation.

> any way around this ?

There is no way to run pre-processor after the program has been compiled and executed.

A better approach is to not duplicate the function definitions, but instead call a function to translate messages before printing output. This translation function should map an argument string into a translated one.